# Does File.Copy return only after file is copied?

Tags: c#

I haven't been able to find an answer to this question, and haven't been sure how to test it.

If I have the following two lines;

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(txtPath,true);

File.Copy(OriginalPath, DestinationPath));

tw.WriteLine("blah");
```

Does the 3rd line wait until the File.Copy is completely done, or could the 3rd line be starting while the File.Copy is still being ran?

Comment: If you don't want to block, read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it will wait, as `File.Copy()` is a synchronous method call / file copy operation.

You can download Visual Studio 2013 Express Edition for Windows Desktop for free, to test out this C# code. [Download link](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx)

Create a new console application project in Visual Studio, and run your code inside the `Main()` method declaration. If you copy a 5-10GB file with your code, you will notice that the call to the `Copy()` method takes some time to return.

Comment: I'm sure he already has Visual Studio, but is unsure of how to test this phenomenon.

Comment: In a new console application project?

Comment: I mean he's not asking for how to run this code, but that he doesn't know how to prove the call returns only after the entire file has been written. You could of course do so by generating a lot of data and writing that (so you'll notice the `Copy()` call takes a while), but then see [@PeterRitchie's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21440465/266143).

Comment: Copy a 5 GB file. Even on a SSD, that will take 10-15 seconds.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not clear on why your asking this, but `File.Copy` is a "synchronous" method--so it won't return until the OS *thinks* it has copied the file.  But, beware, because depending on the drive where the copy is being performed, the write might be cached and not fully written to disk.  Subsequent operations on that disk will take that into account (e.g. if you then tried to copy the first destination to a new one, that would work); but if the disk loses power after `File.Copy` returns, **all the data may not have been written to disk**.  This is a particular problem with some SSD drives.

Answer (score 3):

The framework is generally quite well designed. If a particular method wasn't going to have completed its work by the time it returns, it would return you something by which you could determine when the operation had completed (i.e. `Task`, `Task<T>` or `IAsyncResult`)

`File.Copy` is a `void` method returning nothing, so the expectation is that it has completed its work when it returns.

Comment: +1. Method name also would indicate "async" in some way - `ReadAsync` and like.

Comment: As opposed to, say, php ;D

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I heard rumors that PHP has some kind of naming convention.

Comment: @UweKeim - I've heard that it's even better - it has *multiple* naming conventions

Answer (score 1):

According to [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net), the [`File.Copy` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) internally calls the Win32 [`CopyFile` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at some point which in turn is a synchronous function.

So in my opinion, it is completely synchron, not asynchron. Thus, your 3rd line is called *after* the file is fully copied.

Comment: Whether it is synchronous or asynchronous is a statement of fact, not of opinion.

Comment: He was taking issue with your turn of phase, "So in my opinion". I think it is clear what you meant is "So from this I conclude".